# Problem with shared library libc++.so.1 on kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, android, shared-library

To be clear I ran into this problem before. Last week I install KUBUNTU 18.04 64 bit on my laptop. As an android project required 32-bit version of libc++.so.1 I run

`sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev`

Then restart and rebuild the project. The problem is gone and the project compiles successfully.

Then I decided to install same iso in my desktop. But above command doesn't resolve my issue this time. When I run `ldd Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/lld` on my laptop there is a valid link between `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc++.so.1`. 
But on desktop there is no such file in that directory. Andorid studio is giving following error

`/home/user_name/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/lld: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: **libc++** : The package name is libc++-dev ( or etc. versions ) https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc%2B%2B&searchon=names

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libc++-dev` solve the problem. Thanks a lot, @Knud Larsen. Please make an answer so that I  can accept that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> .. an android project required 32-bit version of libc++.so.1

libc++ : The package name is e.g. libc++1

```
sudo apt install libc++-dev
```

Overview, libc++ versions https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc%2B%2B&searchon=names

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005654/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libncurses-so-5).
I was missing `libncurses5` package. Therefore, `sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386` (for 32 bit version), `sudo apt-get install libncurses5` (for 64 bit version) and `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` (some extra libraries) solved the problem.